# CyanogenMod doesn't work on HTC Sensation XE

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-sensation-xe

I have strange troubles with installation CyanogenMod on HTC Sensation XE. 
Any version (I'v tried 9.0, 9.1, last nightly 10) show about the same errors. There are two classes of errors.

First - /cache/dalvik-cache disappears.

```
    E/dalvikvm(  315): Could not stat dex cache directory '/cache/dalvik-cache': Permission denied
    I/dalvikvm(  315): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/core.jar     (/cache/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex)
    D/dalvikvm(  315): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/core.jar'
    E/dalvikvm(  315): Could not stat dex cache directory '/cache/dalvik-cache': Permission denied
    I/dalvikvm(  315): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/core-junit.jar (/cache/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core-junit.jar@classes.dex)
    D/dalvikvm(  315): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/core-junit.jar'
```

But I created /cache/dalvik-cache before run:

```
    /cache # mkdir dalvik-cache
    /cache # chown system.cache dalvik-cache
    /cache # ls -la
    drwxrwx---    5 system   cache         4096 Mar 31 19:58 .
    drwxr-xr-x   18 root     root             0 Mar 31 19:56 ..
    drwxrwxrwx    2 system   cache         4096 Mar 31 19:58 dalvik-cache
    drwxrwx---    2 root     root          4096 Jan  1  1970 lost+found
    drwxrwx---    2 system   cache         4096 Mar 31 19:31 recovery
    /cache #
```

Second - dalvik waits unexacting jars:

```
    D/dalvikvm(  112): DexOpt: --- END 'apache-xml.jar' (success) ---
    D/dalvikvm(  112): DEX prep '/system/framework/apache-xml.jar': unzip in 33ms, rewrite 964ms
    D/dalvikvm(  112): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/HTCDev.jar'
    D/dalvikvm(  112): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/HTCExtension.jar'
    D/dalvikvm(  112): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/com.htc.framework.jar'
    D/dalvikvm(  112): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'filterfw.jar' (bootstrap=1) ---
    D/dalvikvm(  245): DexOpt: load 12ms, verify+opt 88ms
    D/dalvikvm(  112): DexOpt: --- END 'filterfw.jar' (success) ---
    D/dalvikvm(  112): DEX prep '/system/framework/filterfw.jar': unzip in 8ms, rewrite 256ms
    D/dalvikvm(  112): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/com.htc.android.bluetooth.jar'
    D/dalvikvm(  112): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/wimax.jar'
    D/dalvikvm(  112): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/com.orange.authentication.simcard.jar'
```

The full log is available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1wpz8j7fskf17o/htc-cm.log

Is there any ideas what to do?

Comment: The clues - `/system/framework/HTCDev.jar`, `/system/framework/HTCExtension.jar` and `/system/framework/com.htc.framework.jar`. Is this the official ROM for your handset? Or were you using another variant not designated/adapted?

Comment: I'v downloaded Cyanogen image here: http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=pyramid  These images don't contain HTCExtension.jar etc.

Comment: After scrolling down, and mousing over on the pyramid on the left side of page(from [CM](http://get.cm/) pyramid is for HTC Sensation, not HTC Sensation XE which could explain this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some HTC devices that are unlocked using htc-dev (rather than actually gaining S-Off) required to manually flash the boot.img that you extract from the ROM's zip using fastboot.

```
fastboot flash boot "c:\location\to\boot.img"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to run CM9 and CM10.1 on my Sensation XL. To bypass the cache issue, I added this line to my build.prop file:

```
dalvik.vm.dexopt-data-only=1
```